# Light fixture wiring - black to black, or white to black?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, light-fixture

USA - I’m installing a new ceiling light fixture in a bathroom. The instructions (and every how-to video I watched) said to connect white to white (neutral) and black to black (hot). However, when I detached the old fixture, I found the opposite: the white wire was connected to black and vice versa. It’s been like that for years. Should I connect the new fixture the way it was previously, or follow the instructions? And what could potentially happen if I do it the wrong way? In case it matters: there is also another light fixture in the same room that is controlled by the same switch. First picture provided is the existing configuration. I stopped and left it the way it was because I wasn’t sure how to proceed.

I have now added a second picture of the existing wiring at the switch. There are two switches at this box. The switch on the left controls a fan in the ceiling. The switch on the right controls the light fixture in question along with another light fixture. There are 4 sheaths coming into/out of the switch box, each of which has one black wire, one white, and one ground. I’m not sure which of these delivers power from the house, and which go out to the lights and fan.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the OP has a multimeter I'd suggest measuring the voltage from white to ground and black to ground.  Obviously, the power from black to ground should be about 120volts, and from white to ground, nearly zero.   If not, there are other wiring issues.

Comment: Is the cable in the round ceiling box pictured with the sheath showing from the switch or it is the line hot and its accompanying neutral which is from the electric panel?

Comment: It looks to me like that fixture in the pic is wired wrong. If the sheathed cable comes from the wall switch, then the white would be neutral and should connect to the white lead on the fixture. Are the wires going out of the picture leads for fixture that are part of the fixture? Is that sheathed cable the *only* cable entering the fixture box?

Comment: Do you have a voltage tester?

Comment: Do it per instructions. Incandescent bulbs do not have polarity, so it was not matter before. But your new fixture maybe different.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a voltage tester, and I don’t know where exactly the pictured cable comes from. The light bulb I have been using before is LED.

Comment: Yes, the sheathed cable is the only cable entering the fixture box.

Comment: Traditional incandescent fixtures with sockets for bulbs are wired so that the shell of the socket is neutral and the base contact is hot. That reduces the likelihood of getting an unpleasant surprise while changing bulbs when the circuit is energized, You may be able to visually confirm the connections and can certainly do so with a multimeter.

Comment: This may be a hack job by somebody used to work on automotive or boat wiring.  Black was often used for the negative on a DC 12v circuit (often referred to as the ground when the chassis wasn't used for the negative.  The only way to be sure is to test with a multimeter or open up the switch controlling the light and examine the wiring.

Comment: This was clearly installed improperly.  In this situation, don't even trust the wiring coming in.  Test - and make sure the white wire is actually neutral.  Maybe Joe DIY installed this device box too and got the wires wrong at the other end - then flipped the lamp connections to make it "good" again.  Don't trust anything.  Get a tester and test.  This is a red flag.  Ignore it at your peril.

Comment: In fact, the absurd amount of sheathing in this box seems like a definite tell-tale that this was a DIY job.  No more than 1/2" of outer sheathing should be in the box, so that tells us that the person who ran the cable to this box did not properly know what they were doing.  If it was my house, I would be testing every fixture and outlet in the house after finding this.  There will be more problems.

Comment: I also see a bit of pink insulation up there, meaning that this possibly is an insulated ceiling.  If so, the device box itself does not have a vapour seal shroud so is not suitable for this location (another DIY red flag) and the mangled cutout (another DIY red flag) represents a significant air leak that should be sealed.

Comment: When doing electrical work not having a voltage tester is not an acceptable option. At the big box store with orange buckets a non-contact tester is $6, and a led voltage tester is $13.

Comment: @HotLicks No it doesn't.  There is only one way for this to be correct - the incoming black should be live or switched-live and it should connect to the black wire on the fixture.  The incoming white wire should be neutral and should connect to the white wire.  There is only one 2-wire cable in the box - there are no options here.  Either the lamp is miswired, the incoming cable is miswired, or both, but there is only one correct way for this to be wired.

Comment: I have now updated the original question to add a picture and description of the existing wiring at the switch that controls the light fixture in question. I can’t really make sense of it though to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for adding pic, it's what we needed to see. There's a lot going on in that switch box, but it looks wired right. Only word of caution is most electricians on this website don't like stab in connections. Normal current will cause heating expansion and contraction and the connections tend to come loose. So the general consensus is it is best to release the wires from the stab holes and use the side screw terminals, but that is probably a project that could wait for another day.

Comment: Yes, the wiring in the switch box looks correct, so the wiring at the lamp is simply backwards.  I would **still** test with a tester to be sure.  Agreed with @NoSparksPlease - I'd ditch the backstabs and use the screw terminals.  Always screw in the unused screws also - those unwound screws are another amateur mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I'm sure it's clear to you that the white should be connected to the white, and it should be the neutral.

But just switching the wires really is an incomplete solution, you know they did something wrong, but how wrong? At very least you need a tester to verify that the black is the hot and it is the switched wire. This can simply be done with a no-contact tester or with a volt meter with one lead connected to the bare ground and the other lead testing the black and white for voltage. The black should be the switched hot. If not then you need to at least trace the cable back to it's source, probably the other light, but possibly the switch. It is unlikely but possible that they could have run two switched cables from the switch, rather than one cable from the switch then one cable between lights.

If you find that the wires feeding the junction box are correctly polarized but the fixture is just connected wrong that really wouldn't give me peace, I wouldn't know if it was a single moment of inattentiveness or a pattern inability to follow safety codes. I would want to open the other fixture and probably the switch to verify correct connections. You could then post follow up questions if anything else looks awry.

T̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶n̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶n̶d̶f̶a̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶w̶o̶-̶c̶o̶n̶d̶u̶c̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶.̶ ̶I̶n̶ ̶m̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶e̶u̶t̶r̶a̶l̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶i̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶l̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶p̶e̶r̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶o̶c̶c̶u̶p̶a̶n̶c̶y̶ ̶s̶e̶n̶s̶o̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶i̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶/̶r̶e̶d̶/̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶l̶e̶g̶s̶.̶ ̶I̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶n̶d̶f̶a̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶f̶i̶x̶t̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶f̶e̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶e̶u̶t̶r̶a̶l̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶n̶e̶u̶t̶r̶a̶l̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶n̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶g̶h̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶ ̶(̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶)̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶n̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶p̶a̶r̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶/̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶d̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶.̶ ̶I̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶c̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶(̶s̶u̶p̶p̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶)̶ ̶m̶a̶r̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶a̶p̶e̶,̶ ̶i̶n̶k̶,̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶p̶a̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶w̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶l̶e̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶n̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶f̶i̶x̶t̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶d̶.̶ ̶(̶I̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶h̶o̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶w̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶g̶h̶t̶,̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶w̶o̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶x̶t̶u̶r̶e̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶u̶s̶i̶o̶n̶.̶)̶ ̶

Edit: After seeing your updated picture any talk about switch loops and white being marked and used for anything but neutral doesn't apply, which is good. But since you indicated there is another light on the switch that controls this light, and since the light shown is an end-of-line you still need to verify proper polarity of the wires feeding the light isn't reversed in the intermediate fixture. If you refuse to get a voltage tester a redneck method to verify the polarity at the end light would be to disconnect the white fixture wire from the black building wire, then connect the white fixture wire to the bare building wire. If the switch turns the light on then you need to take apart the other fixture and connect all wires color for color. If nothing happens when you turn the switch on then just connect color for color in that end-of-line j-box and you will be good to go.

Comment: This answer is a little bit "wall of text" but I'm upvoting it because it is the only one that recommends you try to UNDERSTAND the problem better before fixing it.  I'd use a volt meter myself.   take off the fixture and turn on the switch.  make sure black has voltage to ground and white does not.  you identified one backwards connection.  who's to say it's not backwards on the other side too?

Comment: I could get a voltage tester - sounds like that is probably a good idea. I’m just not sure I would know how to use it correctly. But I could give that a try. I appreciate all the info!

Comment: @MattLeonard If you do not have confidence in your ability to learn a new skill correctly, or in your ability to assess your own learning, hire an electrician.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: To follow up: My landlord stopped by with a voltage tester and we determined that the black wire coming out of the ceiling was in fact hot. So we installed the new fixture connecting black to black per the instructions and everything seems good to go!

Comment: @MattLeonard Wait... your **landlord**??  If you're a tenant you should not be doing electrical work on your landlord's property - for a myriad of reasons, not the least of which is that you're not qualified and it's not your house.  You're lucky your landlord is crazy and didn't evict you or sue you.

Comment: @J... In this case I've known my landlord for 8 years and we have a trusting personal relationship. He has allowed me to do work like this in the past and reimbursed me. I don't know if that's legally/technically advisable, but I know him well enough to know he's not going to evict me or sue me, unless I cause serious damage, and he knows me well enough to know that I won't proceed on my own with something he wouldn't approve, or something I don't know how to do, as this post demonstrates.

Comment: @MattLeonard No it is not legally advisable for either of you.  Both of you being OK with the arrangement does not change your landlord's insurer's mind when they decide to not pay for a fire caused by work done by an unlicensed tenant.  It's a huge liability risk for them.

Answer (score 15):

An Edison bulb has a metal "tip" that is totally inaccessible once you start screwing it in.  It does not make contact with the socket until it's screwed all the way in.

It also has an outer metal threaded screw base, which is easily touched while screwing it in.  It makes contact with the sockets "shell" immediately and continuously while screwing it in.

The socket's shell is attached to the white wire.  If you connect that to neutral, then touching a bulb's socket while screwing it in will be harmless unless there's a wiring fault.

Of course if  you connect the socket shell to hot, then if you forgot to turn the switch off, you can get nailed by your finger touching the shell as you screw it in.

Answer (score 3):

This points out the need for understanding the basics of wiring. The light fixture must have a neutral from the house connected to the neutral on the fixture, and will have a switched hot from the switch box connected to the hot connection of the fixture.

The neutral from the house wiring will always be white. If the fixture has wire leads, the fixture neutral will always be white so the neutral connection to the fixture will always be white to white.

The switched hot from the switch however can be either black or white. Therefore, the connection to the hot lead on the fixture can be either black to black or white to black. When a white wire is used as a hot or a switched hot it is supposed to be marked with black tape or a black marker around each end.

There are two ways the house wiring can power a ceiling fixture controlled by a wall switch:

(1) The cable from the house (black always hot, white neutral) goes into the switch box. The black line hot connects to one side of the switch. The white neutral connects to the white of a cable going to the ceiling box.

In the ceiling box the black wire is switched hot and connects to the black lead, and the white is neutral and connects to the white neutral lead of the fixture.

(2) The cable from the house enters in the ceiling fixture box.  In the old wiring method the white neutral connected directly to the white neutral of the fixture and stopped there. The black line hot was connected to either the black or the white of a cable with only black and white going to the switch box. The other wire of the cable was connected to the black lead ofvthe fixture.

In the switch box the two wires (one black and one white were connected respectively to the two contacts on the switch so the white wire either carried the line hot to the switch or the switched hot to the fixture. In this arrangement there was no neutral in the switch box which was OK because the simple mechanical switch did not need one.

Nowadays it is required to have a neutral in the switch box (new construction only) so if the line hot enters in the ceiling, then a three conductor cable (black, red, white) would be required between the ceiling fixture box and the wall switch. The white would be neutral, and the red and black would carry the hot and the switched hot and be connected to the two connections on the switch.

The white neutral would only be connected to the switch  if the switch was one which consumed power, e.g., an electronic timer or a smart switch.

Comment: `the fixture neutral will always be white`  **...if it was installed by a competent person**.  I have certainly seen boxes where the fixture neutral was *not* white - the more red flags a box has, the less you can assume is done correctly.

Comment: I was thinking of factory installed fixture wiring.

Comment: Fair, I meant to quote `The neutral from the house wiring will always be white` - sorry, grabbed the wrong text.